# How to keep precedent widgets after setState

Tags: function, flutter, dictionary, dart, setstate

I want to create a dynamic listview of cards I create with a title and a content. I'm decoding what I receive from the two textfields of the adding page but then when a card is created, it doesn't work well. For the first card, it works perfectly, but when a second one is created, the two cards are the same. I don't really know how to keep my precedent cards while adding new one. If you have any ideas or tips please tell me. Thank you in advance! Here's my code :

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
static List dreams = [];
static List contentCard = [];
String text;
String title;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: kEdgeColor,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: kEdgeColor,
    elevation: 0,
    title: Text('My dreams'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black),
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dreams.length ,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return new DreamCard(
            Content: text,
            title: title,
          );
        }
    )
  ),

  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: kEdgeColor,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [

        FlatButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/public');
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.public),
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        ),

        FlatButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/');
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.bedtime),
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:      (context){return WritingPage();}));
      if (null != result) {
        dreams.add(result);
        Map<String, dynamic> resultat = jsonDecode(result);

        setState(() {text = resultat['text'];
        title = resultat['title'];});
      }
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 30,color: Colors.black,),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,


  ),
  );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause you're only update the title and text when press, and your DreamCard has the same title and text, since you'r not reference items in dreams list by index. so your DreamCard in list always look the same.

```
if (null != result) {
    Map<String, dynamic> resultat = jsonDecode(result);

    // use setState to update your dreams list to trigger UI change
    setState(() {
        dreams.add(resultat);
    });
}

ListView.builder(
    itemCount: dreams.length ,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
        // access item from dreams list by index
        return new DreamCard(
            Content: dreams[index]['text'],
            title: dreams[index]['title],
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your itemBuilder is not referencing index in:

```
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: dreams.length ,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return new DreamCard(
        Content: text,
        title: title,
      );
    }
```

so of course all cards will always has the same text and title as whatever is in scope.  You need to put the data in `dreams` and reference `dreams[index][?something?]` to get the two values appropriate for this card.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the correct text for the next `DreamCard` added because you are adding the `result` received from `WritingPage` page directly to the dreams list. You are then JSON decoding `result` and setting the values of variables `text` and `title`. These values of the latest `WritingPage` are sent to `DreamCard` therefore every `DreamCard` appears to be the same. Instead you should be JSON decoding the `dreams` list and using the `text` and `title` from `dreams` list. Please make the following changes.

```
     return new DreamCard(
        Content: jsonDecode(dreams[index])["text"],
        title: jsonDecode(dreams[index])["title"],
      );
```